# Numpy `searchsorted` far slower than my binary search function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binary-search

I was experimenting with binary search, and when I got my version working I figured I would compare its speed to that of NumPy's. I was fairly surprised at the results, for two reasons.

1. I know that binary search should grow as `log n`, which mine did, but NumPy grew linearly.
2. Not only that, but NumPy was just plain slower -- at the start and certainly at the end.

I attached a graph of the results. Orange is NumPy and blue is mine. To the left is the time in milliseconds it took to find the last item in the list (`items[-1]`) and the bottom shows the length of the list. I have also checked to make sure that my code is returning the correct value and it is.

In case I wasn't clear, my questions are basically "why" two #1 and #2

[image: Pyplot graph NumPy vs my code]

```py
#binary_search.py
from typing import Iterable
from numba import njit
from numba.typed import List


def _find(items: Iterable[int], to_find: int):
    min = -1
    max = len(items)

    while True:
        split = int((max+min)/2)
        item = items[split]
        if item == to_find:
            return split

        elif max == min:
            print(min, max)
            print(items)
            print(to_find)
            print(split)
            exit()

        elif item > to_find:
            max = split - 1
        elif item < to_find:
            min = split + 1


def findsorted(_items: Iterable[int], to_find: int):
    items = _items
    return _find(items, to_find)
```

```py
#graph_results.py
import binary_search as bs
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

iterations = int(sys.argv[1])
items = [0, 1]
lx = []
ly = []
nx = []
ny = []

for i in range(2, iterations):
    l_avg_times = []
    n_avg_times = []
    items.append(items[-1] + 1)
    for _ in range(0, 100):
        to_find = items[-1]
        lstart = time.time()
        bs.findsorted(items, to_find)
        lend = time.time()

        nstart = lend
        np.searchsorted(items, to_find)
        nend = time.time()

        ltotal = lend-lstart
        ntotal = nend-nstart
        l_avg_times.append(ltotal)
        n_avg_times.append(ntotal)
    ly.append(
        round(
            sum(l_avg_times)/len(l_avg_times),
            1000
        )*1000
    )
    lx.append(i)
    ny.append(
        round(
            sum(n_avg_times)/len(n_avg_times),
            1000
        )*1000
    )
    nx.append(i)


plt.plot(lx, ly)
plt.plot(nx, ny)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you ensured both functions also behave the same (that `bs.findsorted(a, b) == np.searchsorted(a, b)` for all `a` and `b`?)

Comment: For one, your implementation doesn't take an array for `b`, whereas Numpy's does. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7e9d603664edc756f555fecf8649bf888a46d47c/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1305-L1306

Comment: @AKX so if I have a large list and want to find the location of an item the best solution is not to use numpy but to use my own code?

Comment: @AKX I just checked and they are equal, both the list passed in and the result.

Comment: I suspect this is simply the effect of `numpy` converting the input, a list, into a numpy.ndarray, which would explain the very linear behavior we are seeing for something that is supposed to be logarithmic.

Comment: @LD you should probably use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) module, simply to avoid re-inventing the wheel. It is implemented in Python, though, so it may not be much faster, but at least, it is well tested and standard.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thanks. I was writing this for fun, not because I actually need this.

Comment: @LD actually, [checking out the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b487e07d0525f7721dcb4dc1aa96eb2eec97a78/Lib/bisect.py#L72) it seems the standard Python distribution [will use an optimized C version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_bisectmodule.c)

Comment: Search times can also depend on where the item is found.

Comment: @hpaulj I always did the last item in the list, for both. I also did each 100 times and took the average for both functions. The result is the graph I showed

Comment: I haven't studied your binary search, but the low dependence of size suggests that it is always finding that last item quickly, without having to look at much of the array.  `searchsorted` has to, I think, do a sort which will take longer with larger arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj actually my binary search is growing logarithmically, it just looks like a line when compared to NumPy.